# Программа на Java сама собой завершается

Tags: intellij-idea, java, обработка-ошибок

Написал игру "Угадай число" по упражнению из учебника по java. В консоли играть не тру, поэтому я решил сразу приделать к ней графический интерфейс. Вроде бы все вышло, но вот проблема, игра сама по себе закрывается после того, как вводишь в поле любое значение. Не могу понять, в чем дело. 
Intellij IDEA, jdk 1.9.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class NumGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard =new Scanner(System.in);
    int popitki = 0;
    int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(10)+1;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "-------------------------------------\n" +
                                        "Добро пожаловать в игру!\n" +
                                        "-------------------------------------");
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Введите любое число от 1 до 9:");
    int inputNum = keyboard.nextInt();
    popitki++;
    while (inputNum!=randomNum) { //программа закрывается вместо того чтобы начинать цикл
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "---------------------------\n"+
                                          "Попытайтесь еще раз\n"+
                                          "---------------------------");
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Введите любое число от 1 до 9:");
        inputNum = keyboard.nextInt();
        popitki++;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "----------------ПОЗДРАВЛЯЕМ-------------------\n"+
                                        "Вы угадали после"+popitki+"попыток\n"+
                                        "----------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: судя по всему проблема с многопоточностью в GUI
нельзя использовать элементы интерфейса в циклах

Comment: @BogdanBida Спасибо за предположение. Посмею не согласится. До этого писал программу с аналогичными элементами интерфейса JOP, которые были расположены внутри цикла 'while' и условного оператора 'if'. Как не странно все запускалось и работало.

Comment: Странно, у меня просто была похожая проблема на python с gui на tkinter, вот и вышло предположение

Comment: А почему вы так странно спрашиваете число, `Scanner` приделали? Он вроде с консолью работает при таких параметрах? Вы же вызываете метод `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)` который возвращает уже готовую строку текста, введённую в GUI.

Comment: @Dmig В таком случае при каких параметрах он работает не с консолью, а с JOP?  Как будет не странно? Я меньше недели как сел кодить. До этого вообще не сном не духом.

Comment: @Dmig Вы меня натолкнули на мысли. Спасибо. Все работает теперь.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @Dmig, натолкнул меня на мысль. Вроде теперь все работает.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class NumGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int popitki = 0;
        int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(10)+1;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "-------------------------------------\n" +
                                            "Добро пожаловать в игру!\n" +
                                            "-------------------------------------");
        String inputNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Введите любое число от 1 до 9:");
        int parseNum = Integer.parseInt (inputNum);
        popitki++;
        while (parseNum!=randomNum) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "----------------------------------\n"+
                                                "Попытайтесь еще раз\n"+
                                                "----------------------------------");
            inputNum =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Введите любое число от 1 до 9:");
            parseNum = Integer.parseInt (inputNum);
            popitki++;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "---------ПОЗДРАВЛЯЕМ----------\n"+
                                            "Вы угадали после " +popitki+ " попыток\n"+
                                            "-------------------------------------------");
        }
}
```